# Symfony - token storage return anonymous

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In my Symfony project I am persisting some entity object, and in that method field I am trying to set logged user.

When dumping results it says:

```
"anon."
```

Think it means 'anonymous.'

Still, I am logged in, but:

```
/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
) {
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

$new->setUserId($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
```

And the error says:

> Expected value of type "App\Entity\User" for association field "App\Entity\MyEntity#$userId", got "string" instead."

Why I am not able to get logged user?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony tries to get your User from MyEntity but the getters used by Symfony seem poorly implemented.

Verify the User class which implements UserInterface (from Symfony).

Verify your doctrine mapping (MyEntity - User) if there isn't the wrong type specified on $userId.